# Airflow lowering performance?

Tags: linux, logstash, airflow

I'm using Apache Airflow (1.9) to run a bash script (which starts Logstash to query data from a database and transfers this data into ElasticSearch).

When I run my script from Airflow, it takes about 95 minutes to complete. When I run the exact same script from the terminal (on the same machine) this task takes 65 minutes to complete.

I really can't figure out what's going on. I'm running a very simple instance of Airflow, using the LocalExecutor. My dag is really really simple, as shown below. I'm not using any fancy stuff, such as variables Xcom or whatsoever.

My dag:

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Me',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2018, 4, 12),
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=1),
    'sla': dt.timedelta(hours=2),
    'depends_on_past': False,
}

syncQDag = DAG('q13', catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 1 * * *', concurrency=1)

l13 = BashOperator(task_id='q13', bash_command='sudo -H -u root /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash-manual -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/q13.conf', dag=syncQDag)
```

Is there any clear reason why a job initiated through Airflow performs about 50% worse? As all the same components are used and running while the job is executed I'd suggest there's no real difference between execution through Airflow compared to from the terminal? Or am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure of the reason, but did you also compare the process priority and niceness?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just checked this, both cases are identical (NI 0, PRI 80).

Comment: The bash operator captures the processes' pipes and stores them, it could be related. Is there supposed to be a lot of output from this? The config can run_as_user if you enabled this.

Comment: What kind of output do you mean? I can configure the verbosity of the Logstash output to the terminal (stdout). I'll check if increasing / decreasing verbosity is of any effect. The task itself generates about 2 million JSON documents, which are stored into ElasticSearch. Those 2 million documents embody about 2.4Gb....